# Como puedo hacer esta modificación con php en mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Actualmente estoy realizando un proyecto que posee 5 tablas en una misma base de datos, la clave primaria de todas estas tablas es CedulaAlumno y es el dato que solícito para buscar si esta el alumno o no en la tabla, luego que solícito la CedulaAlumno a través de un form no se como conectar y modificar las tablas de manera que:

1. Me aparezca todos los campos de todas las tablas.
2. Realizar las modificaciones correspondiente y que se puedan guardar los datos en todas las tablas de una sola vez. Espero que me puedan ayudar o al menos sugerirme como resolverlo, muchas gracias.

```
$Registros = mysqli_query($Conexion, "select TipoCedulaAlumno, alumnos.CedulaAlumno, PrimerApellidoAlumno, SegundoApellidoAlumno, PrimerNombreAlumno, SegundoNombreAlumno, FechaNacimientoAlumno, NacionalidadAlumno, EdadAlumno, SexoAlumno, DireccionAlumno, TelefonoAlumno, CorreoAlumno, EstadoAlumno, InstitutoProcedencia, AsignaturaPendiente, AsignaturaQueCursa, TipoCedulaRepresentante, CedulaRepresentante, PrimerApellidoRepresentante, SegundoApellidoRepresentante, PrimerNombreRepresentante, SegundoNombreRepresentante, NacionalidadRepresentante, EdadRepresentante, DireccionRepresentante, TelefonoRepresentante, CorreoRepresentante, ProfesionRepresentante, DireccionTrabajoRepresentante, TelefonoTrabajoRepresentante, ParentescoEstudiante, DireccionEmergencia, PrimerApellidoPadres, SegundoApellidoPadres, PrimerNombrePadres, SegundoNombrePadres, DireccionPadres, TelefonoPadres, CertificadoSaludEscolar, BoletinInformativo, CertificadoAprobacion, PartidaNacimiento, CopiasPartidaNacimiento, CopiasCedulaAlumno, CopiasCedulaRepresentante, FotoAlumno, FotoRepresentante from alumnos inner join representantes on representantes.CedulaAlumno inner join estatusalumno on estatusalumno.CedulaAlumno inner join padres on padres.CedulaAlumno inner join documentos on documentos.CedulaAlumno = alumnos.CedulaAlumno") or die ("Problemas en el select: ".mysqli_error($Conexion)); 

if ($Reg = mysqli_fetch_array($Registros)) 

{
    echo "Cedula del Alumno: ".$Reg['TipoCedulaAlumno']." ".$Reg['CedulaAlumno']."<br>";
    echo "Apellidos del Alumno: ".$Reg['PrimerApellidoAlumno']." ".$Reg['SegundoApellidoAlumno']."<br>";
    echo "Nombres del Alumno: ".$Reg['PrimerNombreAlumno']." ".$Reg['SegundoNombreAlumno']."<br>";
    echo "Fecha de Nacimiento del Alumno: ".$Reg['FechaNacimientoAlumno']."<br>";
    echo "Nacionalidad del Alumno: ".$Reg['NacionalidadAlumno']."<br>";
    echo "Edad del Alumno: ".$Reg['EdadAlumno']."<br>";
    echo "Sexo del Alumno: ".$Reg['SexoAlumno']."<br>";
    echo "Direccion del Alumno: ".$Reg['DireccionAlumno']."<br>";
    echo "Telefono del Alumno: ".$Reg['TelefonoAlumno']."<br>";
    echo "Correo del Alumno: ".$Reg['CorreoAlumno']."<br>";
    echo "<br><br>";//                    SE DEBE DIVIDIR EN VARIOS DIV Y COLOCARLE UN PADDING A CADA SESSION//


    echo "Estado del Alumno: ".$Reg['EstadoAlumno']."<br>";
    echo "Instituto de Procedencia: ".$Reg['InstitutoProcedencia']."<br>";
    echo "Asignaturas Pendientes: ".$Reg['AsignaturaPendiente']."<br>";
    echo "Asignatura Que Cursa: ".$Reg['AsignaturaQueCursa']."<br>";
    echo "<br><br>";//                    SE DEBE DIVIDIR EN VARIOS DIV Y COLOCARLE UN PADDING A CADA SESSION//


    echo "Cedula del Representante: ".$Reg['TipoCedulaRepresentante']." ".$Reg['CedulaRepresentante']."<br>";
    echo "Apellidos del Representante. ".$Reg['PrimerApellidoRepresentante']." ".$Reg['SegundoApellidoRepresentante']."<br>";
    echo "Nombres del Representante: ".$Reg['PrimerNombreRepresentante']." ".$Reg['SegundoNombreRepresentante']."<br>";
    echo "Nacionalidad del Representante: ".$Reg['NacionalidadRepresentante']."<br>";
    echo "Edad del Representante: ".$Reg['EdadRepresentante']."<br>";
    echo "Direccion del Representante: ".$Reg['DireccionRepresentante']."<br>";
    echo "Telefono del Representante: ".$Reg['TelefonoRepresentante']."<br>";
    echo "Correo del Representante: ".$Reg['CorreoRepresentante']."<br>";
    echo "Profesion del Representante: ".$Reg['ProfesionRepresentante']."<br>";
    echo "Direccion de trabajo del Representante: ".$Reg['DireccionTrabajoRepresentante']."<br>";
    echo "Telefono de Trabajo del Representante: ".$Reg['TelefonoTrabajoRepresentante']."<br>";
    echo "Parentesco con el Estudiante: ".$Reg['ParentescoEstudiante']."<br>";
    echo "Direccion de Emergencia: ".$Reg['DireccionEmergencia']."<br>";
    echo "<br><br>";//                    SE DEBE DIVIDIR EN VARIOS DIV Y COLOCARLE UN PADDING A CADA SESSION//


    echo "Apellidos de los Padres: ".$Reg['PrimerApellidoPadres']." ".$Reg['SegundoApellidoPadres']."<br>";
    echo "Nombres de los Padres: ".$Reg['PrimerNombrePadres']." ".$Reg['SegundoNombrePadres']."<br>";
    echo "Direccion de los Padres: ".$Reg['DireccionPadres']."<br>";
    echo "Telefono de los Padres: ".$Reg['TelefonoPadres']."<br>";
    echo "<br><br>";//                    SE DEBE DIVIDIR EN VARIOS DIV Y COLOCARLE UN PADDING A CADA SESSION//


    echo "Certificado de Salud: ".$Reg['CertificadoSaludEscolar']."<br>";
    echo "Boletin Informativo: ".$Reg['BoletinInformativo']."<br>";
    echo "Certificado de Aprobacion: ".$Reg['CertificadoAprobacion'];
    echo "Partida de Nacimiento: ".$Reg['PartidaNacimiento']."<br>";
    echo "Copias de la Partida de Nacimiento: ".$Reg['CopiasPartidaNacimiento']."<br>";
    echo "Copias de la Cedula del ALumno: ".$Reg['CopiasCedulaAlumno']."<br>";
    echo "Copias de la Cedula del Representante: ".$Reg['CopiasCedulaRepresentante']."<br>";
    echo "Fotos del Alumno: ".$Reg['FotoAlumno']."<br>";
    echo "Fotos del Representante: ".$Reg['FotoRepresentante']."<br>";
    echo "<br><br>";//                    SE DEBE DIVIDIR EN VARIOS DIV Y COLOCARLE UN PADDING A CADA SESSION//

}

 else

{
 echo "No se encontro un alumno con esa Cedula";
}

mysqli_close($Conexion);
 ?>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**La tabla alumno tiene:** CedulaAlumno (Primary key), TipoCedulaAlumno, PrimerApellidoAlumno, SegundoApellidoAlumno, PrimerNombreAlumno, SegundoNombreAlumno, FechaNacimientoAlumno, NacionalidadAlumno, EdadAlumno, SexoAlumno, DireccionAlumno, TelefonoAlumno, CorreoAlumno.

**La tabla representantes tiene:** CedulaAlumno (Primary key), TipoCedulaRepresentante, PrimerApellidoRepresentante, SegundoApellidoRepresentante, PrimerNombreRepresentante, SegundoNombreRepresentante, NacionalidadRepresentante, EdadRepresentante, DireccionRepresentante, TelefonoRepresentante, CorreoRepresentante, ProfesionRepresentante, DireccionTrabajoRepresentante, TelefonoTrabajoRepresentante, ParentescoEstudiante, DireccionEmergencia.

**La tabla padres tiene:** CedulaAlumno (Primary key), PrimerApellidoPadres, SegundoApellidoPadres, PrimerNombrePadres, SegundoNombrePadres, DireccionPadres, TelefonoPadres.

**La tabla documentos tiene:** CedulaAlumno (Primary Key), CertificadoSaludEscolar, BoletinInformativo, CertificadoAprovacion, PartidaNacimiento, CopiasPartidaNacimiento, CopiasCedulaAlumno, CopiasCedulaRepresentante, FotoAlumno, FotoRepresentante.

Vale acotar que solo la muestro una vez en la consulta y es la tabla alumnos.CedulaAlumno, Pero si llegase a modificar la cédula en la tabla alumnos también debo hacerlo en las otras.

Comment: Disculpe no entiendo que corrigió del código y como debería hacer la pantalla para cargar los nuevos datos?

Comment: Por favor, explica como están estructuradas las 5 tablas. Qué columnas tiene cada una.

Answer (score 0):

supongo que quieres unir los campos de todas las tablas para mostrarlos en una sola pagina no ?  o me equivoco ?
Si es así la consulta que haces en tu servidor debería incluir un join así  te devolverá todos los campos en una sola consulta
y  2 creo que no se podrían guardar cambios en todas las tablas de un solo golpe puedes poner un método debajo del otro para que se guarden una tras otra al pulsar un solo botón pero no podrías guardar de un solo golpe todo ya que supongo algunas tablas manejan llaves foráneas hacia otras tablas no ? y necesitas conocer el id insertado en la  tabla referenciada para almacenar datos en otra. En mysql me parece que hay una función llamada last_insert o algo así que te devuelve el ultimo id insertado

Comment: Buenas tardes, cada tabla tiene solo una primary key que es "Cedula.Alumno" no poseo claves foráneas, ya que todos los datos son del alumno, solo quería realizar la modificación de un solo golpe ya que el insert lo realizo así, inserto la información de golpe a las 5 tablas. y en la consulta igual.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que el problema en el que estás parado es de interfaz con el usuario más que de *php/mysql*.

No sé como traes el `$CedulaAlmuno`, si por sesión, `POST` o `GET`; Pero cada tabla que intentas presentar puede tranquilamente ser consultada por separado y guardarlo en un Array para cada tabla y que luego lo imprimas sobre el código de vista, ya que es por un solo alumno en vez de todos los del colegio. Ejemplo:

```
SQL: SELECT FROM `tabla` WHERE `CedulaAlumno`='xxx'
while... $Reg['columna']...

$tabla1 = array(
    'cedula' => $Reg['TipoCedulaAlumno'],
    'apellidos' => $Reg['PrimerApellidoAlumno'],
    'nombres' => $Reg['PrimerNombreAlumno'],
    'nacimiento' => $Reg['FechaNacimientoAlumno']
    /*... etc.*/
);
```

Lo mismo para las otras tablas.

Luego, sobre el *HTML* imprimes dentro de la etiqueta que designes, accediendo al array de la tabla como `echo $tabla1['nombres'];`.

Answer (score -1):

Para obtener todos los datos puede unir los resultados con un join, lo que te obliga a tener el mismo numero de campos en las tablas, lo cual no soluciona tu problema, pero si, usando el comando UNION

```
SELECT * FROM TABLA1 WHERE Condicion 1 UNION SELECT * FROM TABLA2 WHERE Condicion2
```

Para el update, lamentablemente, tendrás que realizar una consulta por tabla, salvo que te permita crear algún tipo de procedimiento almacenado, lo cual solo va a provocar que los updates esten en el procedimiento almacenado, en lugar del codigo.

Otra opción para los datos, es crearse vistas, pero no te lo recomiendo

Comment: Al contrario: usando `union` o `union all` te obliga a tener el mismo numero de campos en las tablas. mientras que `join` no tiene ese problema. De modo que la consulta tal como la tienes no va a funcionar. Y aun si "funcionara", el resultado no tendría sentido. `join` es la opción correcta en este caso.